# Chakra-UI for windows

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

Any decent [Chakra-UI](https://chakra-ui.com/) tutorials for Windows? From setting up react to a full working demo? Can't seem to find any good medium articles on this. The official site is more nix based

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter if you're running Windows, or any other operating system. If you're looking to get started with Chakra UI, check out my free course: https://egghead.io/courses/build-a-modern-user-interface-with-chakra-ui-fac68106

If you're having any issues, let me know!

Thanks!